# Sha1  Certificate Fingerprint

Tags: android, sha1, google-maps-api-2

немного измененный предыдущий вопрос.
Скорее всего я где то жестко торможу, получаю ошибку авторизации

```
 10-21 16:56:13.180: E/Google Maps Android API(26958): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
10-21 16:56:13.190: E/Google Maps Android API(26958): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.tk.lechenievchehii, API Key: AIzaSyCBZzfhP7LaBCPFgb6o8wb7Uqc_ewMfgMQ, Certificate Fingerprint: 7890654CEE9396F9286F86C47A892E030B01F698
10-21 16:56:28.525: E/Google Maps Android API(26958): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

по ссылке естественно я ходил, по сути по ней и работал, уже попробовал создать новое хранилище ketstore  вот что пишу в консоли

```
    c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.a
    d\anri_map.keystore" -alias anri_map -storepass qwerty -keypass 123456
    Alias name: anri_map
    Creation date: 21.10.2013
    Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
    Certificate chain length: 1
    Certificate[1]:
    Owner: CN=gadfil
    Issuer: CN=gadfil
    Serial number: 723ee5
    Valid from: Mon Oct 21 16:25:28 FET 2013 until: Fri Oct 15 16:25:28 FET 203
    Certificate fingerprints:
             MD5:  83:73:FA:9D:30:63:A9:F9:68:6E:A3:62:B0:20:1B:93
             SHA1: 35:B8:1D:90:C3:E8:D6:DD:C2:DB:CA:2F:D2:A5:E1:85:06:CE:18:7B
             SHA256: F8:C4:F0:F5:B6:F6:26:8D:5E:09:F0:75:65:2B:20:6F:38:AD:37:8
    43:97:41:78:C7:4A:DC:BB:61:B4:9F
             Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
             Version: 3

    Extensions:

    #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
    SubjectKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: F7 6F 83 BB 26 83 29 56   CF 70 6D FE CF A4 8A FF  .o..&.)V.pm.....
    0010: 69 5F 3B 5C                                        i_;\
    ]
    ]
```

копирую sha1 35:B8:1D:90:C3:E8:D6:DD:C2:DB:CA:2F:D2:A5:E1:85:06:CE:18:7B и генерирую в консоли ключ, откуда в логе берется

```
 Certificate Fingerprint: 7890654CEE9396F9286F86C47A892E030B01F698
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно пригодится кому то. Не знаю в чем дело - возможно в том что установлено android studio и intellj idea ... удалил их, удалил папку .android и приложение с телефона - установил все по новой, получил новый ключ - работает.